# Rails 3. Find documents of a certain category with a has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, kaminari

I have the following models

```
Document
has_many :document_categorizations
has_many :document_categories, through: :document_categorizations

DocumentCategory
has_many :document_categorizations
has_many :documents, through: :document_categorizations

DocumentCategorization
belongs_to :document_category
belongs_to :document
```

In my index action, I can filter the documents by category...

```
def index
  if params[:category_id].nil?
    @documents = Document.page(params[:page]).per(15)
  else
    @documents = DocumentCategory.find(params[:category_id]).documents
    @category = DocumentCategory.find(params[:category_id])
  end    
  ....
end
```

I can't use `DocumentCategory.find(params[:category_id]).documents` anymore because I just added kaminari for pagination and I need to make the query at the Document model not DocumentCategory.

**How can I query for documents of a certain category?**

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It almost looks like `DocumentCategorization` is unnecessary

Comment: Wait, I thought `kaminari` worked on a relation. It seems like there isn't a reason that shouldn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: @varatis I need DocumentCategorization because a document can belong to many categories.

Comment: @Azolo What I have currently does work. but how can I setup pagination for `DocumentCategory.find(params[:category_id]).documents` or maybe I need to modify that query to add pagination to it.

Comment: @leonel It seem like this is a HABTM situation then, and you are not setting up your tables correctly. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many

Comment: @varatis http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many

Comment: `DocumentCategory.find(params[:category_id]).documents.page(params[:page]).per(15)` Doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Ah! So easy. That's what happens when you code several hours straight. I think I just needed to take a break and gain a little perspective, all of the sudden it just hit me.

```
@category = DocumentCategory.find(params[:category_id])
@documents = @category.documents.page(params[:page]).per(15)
```